# Which is the correct setting to show unused code in VS Code/Dart?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's 2022 and VS Code doesn't seem to naturally show unused variables, functions etc.

After researching this issue I found some threads from around 2018 where people tried to solve this by editing `settings.json` like:

```json
//in settings.json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#ff0000"
}
```

This setting seemed to work BEFORE 2018 versions, but how can I visually mark unused code in 2022? There MUST be a way...

Edit: I am using Dart lang.

Comment: it is done by the language server with semantic highlighting, it works at least in JavaScript/Typescript/Python, most likely in C/C++

Comment: Thank you, but I am using Dart and it doesn't work like it should. I will edit my post... thanks anyway.

Comment: add a feature request at the Dart language extension repo to add semantic tokens